# Rust unresolved import no `size_t` in the root

Tags: rust

I've got a project that builds for ios, android and wasm targets, when I build for ios and android everything works but when I build for wasm I get the following error;

[image]

Im unsure what this error message actually means, I'm using an external crate libc, here's the code from my `src/string.rs` file

```rust
use libc::size_t;

// Helper struct that is used to give strings to C.
#[repr(C)]
pub struct StringPtr {
  pub ptr: *const u8,
  pub len: size_t,
}

impl<'a> From<&'a str> for StringPtr {
  fn from(s: &'a str) -> Self {
    StringPtr {
      ptr: s.as_ptr(),
      len: s.len() as size_t,
    }
  }
}

impl StringPtr {
  pub fn as_str(&self) -> &str {
    use std::{slice, str};

    unsafe {
      let slice = slice::from_raw_parts(self.ptr, self.len);
      str::from_utf8(slice).unwrap()
    }
  }
}
```

and inside my `lib.rs` file I've got the following to import my `string.rs` file

```rust
extern crate libc;
mod string;
use string::StringPtr;
```

It's also worth noting that I am using cfg to conditionally include different code for different targets, maybe this is part of the problem?

Comment: Do not post images. Include the errors as text.

Comment: What target are you using? I guess it's `wasm32-unknown-unknown` (and not `wasm32-unknown-emscripten` nor `wasm32-wasi`). Am I correct?

Comment: AFAIK there is no `libc` for pure WASM targets, only for WASI. What I did once was to conditionally add a type alias `type size_t  = usize;`.